# Linux dd Command - Possible to do a full disk copy from larger to smaller drive?

Tags: linux, clone, dd

I have a 500 gig drive as well as an 80 gig drive. I would like to clone the 500 gig over to the 80 gig and I think it might work because there is not 80 gigs of data on the 500 gig drive.

Will this work?

Comment: That is an abuse of the word "clone", which implies an exact copy.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some special reason for doing this (milions or billions of small files for example) it will be easier to just copy the files from one drive to ther other.

If you must do it this way, then you should resize the partition on the 500GB drive first, because even if it contains less than 80GB of data, this data may be scattered all over the disk. So take these steps:

1. Resize the partition on the 500GB to 80GB (using `gparted` for example)
2. Create a partition of the same size and type on the 80GB drive.
3. Use `dd` to copy from partition to partition.